# Cardinality with primes

Tags: prime-numbers, set-theory, cardinals

My friend asked me this question. I would appreciate your understanding even if my English is not perfect.

For any prime number ${p}$, let's define a set ${P}$ that consists of all multiples of ${p}$. Also, let's define a set ${S}$ that contains all multiples of each prime number smaller than ${p}$.
If we consider the set of all natural numbers as ${N}$, how do the sizes of the following two sets compare?

$N \cap S^C$ and $P$

For example, if ${p=7}$:
$$P= \{7,14,21,28,35,42,… \}$$
$$S= \{2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,21,… \}$$
$$N \cap S^{C}=\{1,7,11,13,17,19,… \}$$
I believe I can establish a one-to-one correspondence between $N \cap S^{C}$ and ${P}$, so I think they have the same cardinality as ${N}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Indeed you are correct. In general every infinite subset of $\Bbb N$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb N$, which is not terribly hard to prove!